# Autogrowing RecyclerView From Json Feed

Tags: android, json, rss, android-recyclerview

I have a json feed. I have to display the data in a recyclerview, I have done this in a smooth way, and it works. the feed contains information about 50 movies and if i change the limit in feed link i will get more details (ex : https://myfeed_example.com/rss/topmovies/limit=50/json) if I change the limit to 100 I will get 100 feeds, thats how it works, right now how I am parsing  is first I am fetching the whole json feed and iterates through and shows in a recyclerview. that means it will display 50 movie details in the list.

but what I want is first I have to show details of 20 movies, and when the user reaches at the bottom of list, have to load remaining 20 and so on. there are two ways we can follow for this.

1. If a real time json reader is available, we can read parse feed and 
   display
2. We can download all the feed for the first time and and parse all and put in memory and load required data, like that we can do.

which is the correct approach for making an autogrowing list ?

Answer (score 0):

The first option is the correct one.
Then in your Recylcerview adapter append to the list of movies using something like this.

```
public void appendMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
    int size = mMovies.size();
    mShots.addAll(movies);
    notifyItemRangeInserted(size, mMovies.size());
}
```